# cannot run karma test on react app: "cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, karma-jasmine

I'm using React with typescript and I'm trying to execute karma tests. When I run test, I get this error: "Cannot use import statement outside a module". I've tried to set `"type": "module"` in the package.json and added webpack configurations in the karma.conf.ts but nothing seems to work.

Here's my karma.conf.ts file:

```
module.exports = (config) => {
  config.set({
    basePath: "",
    frameworks: ["jasmine", "karma-typescript"],
    files: [
      {
        pattern: "../src/test/**/*.spec.+(ts|tsx)",
        included: true,
        watched: true,
        served: true,
        type: "js"
      },
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: { "test/**/*.spec.+(ts|tsx)": ["karma-typescript"] },
    reporters: ["progress", "karma-typescript"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ["ChromeHeadless"],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity,
    webpack: {
      configure: {
          module: {
              rules: [
                  {
                      resolve: {
                          fullySpecified: false,
                      },
                  },
              ],
          },
      },
  },
  });
};
```

And here's my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.58",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.13",
    "karma-typescript": "^5.5.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^13.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.17.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.9.0",
    "sass": "^1.69.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "lint": "eslint --fix .",
    "test": "karma start config/karma.conf.ts",
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "plugins": [
      "prettier"
    ],
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "prettier/prettier": 2,
      "react/jsx-key": "error"
    },
    "ignorePatterns": [
      "public/"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "prettier": {
    "endOfLine": "auto"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/react-scroll": "^1.8.10",
    "jasmine-core": "^5.1.1",
    "karma": "^6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-requirejs": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "karma-typescript-preprocessor": "^0.4.0",
    "karma-webpack": "^5.0.0",
  }
}
```